# Extracting single file from Zip input stream object

Tags: java, android, c, file, java-native-interface

I need to extract a single file from Zip-input stream object of 1200+ files. Extracting a single file using getNextEntry() API of ZipInputStream class will be costly operation. Is there any way to extract single file without writing  Zip-input stream object to physical location ???

Note :

Atleast, Is there any way to achieve above requirement using miniunz.c, unzip.c or other native libraries. I have explored miniunz.c and unzip.c, and I didn't find any way.

Comment: put some code of `input stream`

Comment: If you want random access, do not use `ZipInputStream`. [Use `ZipFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile).

Comment: I cannot use ZipFile class, as it needs file object. Because of security measures, I have to extract file from stream object only.

Comment: so you have to play with `getNextEntry` - there is no other way to "skip" directly to the right entry